# Automatic dark detector: base voltage

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, ldr

Here we have the typical “automatic dark detector” circuit:

[image: automatic dark detector circuit]

Let’s assume LDR=5Kohm with light, and LDR=2Mohm in darkness, the battery is 12V instead of 9V, and the transistor has a forward voltage Vbe=0.7V.

With light, per the voltage divider formula, we have Vbase=0.57V and the transistor is cut off.

In darkness, the formula gives Vbase=11.42V. Since this is much higher than 0.7V.  Why does the transistor not burn?

Comment: That's not even a good topology for this. I would not even consider it. But to answer your question, you've forgotten the Thevenin impedance of the divider pair, haven't you?

Comment: @jonk thank you very much for your comment. Yes, definitely I am missing something very basic :) I’m going to research the Thevenin impedance concept: https://youtu.be/xSRe_4TQbuo?t=656

Comment: I don't think you included the base-emitter junction's impedance in your voltage divider equations.

Comment: @user_1818839 That's usually pretty small. Ten or twenty Ohms. Or so. The emitter will have some, but usually less than one ohm.

Comment: @jonk oops, edited comment.

Comment: @user_1818839 Doesn't matter. The only important effect is the Thevenin impedance of the divider.

Comment: That better not be a typical dark detector. When the LED is on, the voltages across R1 and R2 will be (very roughly) the same. So the current in R1 (and the LED) will be about 1000 times that of R2. By definition, this requires the transistor to have a gain of about 1000. That won't happen at the best of times, and this isn't the best of times, A BJT being operated as a switch (the term is "in saturation") will have a gain of about 10 to 20.

Comment: @jonk ok, so the Thevenin equivalent (in darkness) is Vt=11.42V and Rt=95.23ohm. So, let’s see if I understood it: I have 11.42V in the base of the transistor but the current will be limited by the resistor to about 120mA, within specs. So it “does not matter” at which voltage we put the base, if the current is within specs?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast yes :) by “typical” I meant the first I found. Don’t know if it works; that’s what I am trying to understand. Thank you very much for your comment!

Comment: @ElectroNewbie With 2M and 100k you don't get 95 Ohms. Did you forget the k there?

Comment: @jonk yes, sorry and thanks for your patience :( Rt=95.23Kohm, so… current is 11.42/95.23K=0.12mA? What voltage do we have on the transistor base?

Comment: @jonk ok, I think it has to be calculated using KVL. (11.42-0.7)/95.23K=0.112mA. So if beta is let’s say 100, we have Ic=11.2mA. If we asume 20mA for good LED light, we would have half brightness. I suppose a second NPN is needed to potentially amplify more the output current, or that there are better ways to do it.

Comment: @ElectroNewbie You'd want less beta, given that BJT is to be operating in saturation. So yes, more BJTs. But. You will also want hysteresis.

Comment: @jonk yes, perhaps something more advanced (for me!) like this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/300505  thank you very much for your time and comments.

Comment: @ElectroNewbie Here are a few I wrote: [LDR 1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/265220/38098), [LDR 2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/354391/38098), [LDR 3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/317775/38098), [LDR 4](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/376460/38098), and [LDR 5](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/268897/38098), in no particular order.

Answer (score 1):

The resistor divider calculator only applies if the NPN's base-emitter doesn't clamp the voltage. However it does - so you can calculate that R2 runs 9-0.7 V, or 83 uA. The 2 MΩ LDR 'removes' 0.7/2M of that (0.35 uA), so basically all R2's current drives the NPN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, intuitively I see that when the LDR is very high R2 dominates the circuit and current gets aplied to the base. But what I don’t get is why the base is at 0.7V. Why this holds? Is it a property of the BE “diode” or something like that?

Comment: I think the key word in your answer is “clamp” the voltage. What does it mean that the base-emitter clamps the voltage? Does it get “fixed” at 0.7V above earth? I’m sure this is all trivial stuff. Thank you all for your patience. Will try to understand better the case in which we only have a resistor and a diode in series.

Comment: Ok, I think it must be calculated simply using KVL. The voltage drop across the BE diode is 0.7V, so that’s the voltage at the base of the transistor.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer jp312.